# Reconocimiento en django de Python

Tags: python, django

He instalado django,no tuve ningun problema,me creo la subcarpeta dentro de mi carpeta,pero no con .py para que lo lea python , me creo la subcarpeta__pycache__ ,me creo **init** , settings , urls y wsgi pero sin .py y no se como solucionarlo porque sin .py no me estaria permitiendo que python me lo reconozca.python lo reconoció al momento de instalar django. Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿has creado el proyecto con `django-admin startproject NombreDelProyecto`?

Comment: ¿No estarás usando windows? Si es así, configura el explorador de ficheros para que muestre las extensiones. La carpeta `__pycache__` es señal de que python está interpretando los ficheros python. Concretamente, ¿qué error te sale para que supongas que no está reconociendo correctamente los ficheros?

Comment: buenas tardes y gracias por responderme,si , cree el proyecto con django admin ,lo hice mirando un tutorial de pildoras informaticas.y por otro lado si,tengo windows 7 ,no me sale un error en si, pero al mirar el tutorial vi que aparecian esos digamos modulos con.py y el mio no lo tiene.¿eso me crearia un problema a futuro?.muchas gracias!feliz dia del trabajador(atrasado).